# Designing Tables for Regular Updates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains information about transactions, currently totaling 50 million rows. The table has 16 columns, with 4 of them being indexed. Transactions are frequently inserted, around 100 per minute, and this rate is expected to increase. Importantly, transactions are never deleted.

Transactions are initially created and then processed by an external service. If the processing is successful, three specific columns in the table are updated with the relevant data from the external service. In case of service unavailability or other failures, a periodic task continuously attempts to process the transactions until successful. Each row is updated at most once.

Now, I'm considering whether it's beneficial to create a separate table for processed transactions. This new table would store a foreign key pointing to the original transaction and the three columns updated by data from the external service. The motivation behind this is that, at times, the external service may be unavailable for a few hours, resulting in a backlog of hundreds of transactions to be updated once the service becomes available. However, I'm concerned about the added complexity of introducing a new table and the need for a join in nearly all read operations.

Comment: Not really clear what problem you're trying to solve here. Your post's title asks about optimizing performance but the post doesn't really mention anything in regards to performance, especially regarding this larger table. Why does it matter if the external service has to update a few hundred rows at a time, infrequently?...that's a tiny update. "*Transactions are frequently inserted, around 30 per second*' - Is this accurate, 24/7?...because that would indicate your database is only about 12 days old since that comes out to roughly 2.5 million new rows a day.

Comment: "The motivation behind this is that, at times, the external service may be unavailable for a few hours, resulting in a backlog of hundreds of transactions to be updated once the service becomes available."  That is not a good motivation.  Who cares if there is a backlog?  What problems does it cause which you are trying to avoid or solve?

Comment: @J.D.
I'm new to relational databases and I know that my question may seem basic. After revisiting my initial numbers, I realize the table load is less significant than initially stated, leading to some confusion in my query. My concern is about best practices for table design, particularly regarding updates and potential issues like table bloat impacting vacuum efficiency. Though unsure about the severity in my case, I'm considering an append-only design. In essence, I seek input on whether my concerns about update performance are valid or unwarranted. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @Daulet No worries, usually one doesn't concern themselves with performance problems until they have one concretely since they're very fact specific, which is why the confusion. I can't speak specifically to vacuuming but best practices for table design is generally to follow the design of your objects and how they'll be used in the consuming applications. (It's that simple because then you're persisting the data how it'll be used.) Again, only special implementations are recommended when a specific performance problem is encountered, and depending on what that actual problem is. Best of luck!

Comment: @J.D. I understand now, thank you!